# Test Code Coverage: What do the numbers mean?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage

What do these test counts represent?

I look at the 4 & 5 and don't understand their differences when looking at the code:

[image]

versus...
[image]

Are they a count of something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers represent the number of times the function was called when running the unit tests. In your first example the numberOfRowsInSection function was called 4 times when running the unit tests. In your second example the cellForRowAt function was called 5 times during the unit tests.